# glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S) GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c++, opengl, shadow

I'm currently working on a shadow Mapping thing. I found Paul's Projects http://www.paulsprojects.net/tutorials/smt/smt.html, and I'm currently trying to implement this. But I'm not able to get a proper solution.

Does anyone of you guys have any idea why putting a glPushMatrix(), glPopMatrix() pair for each glmodelview- and glprojection-matrix around the whole drawing process (all 3 necessary shadow-pathes) would cause any GL_INVALID_OPERATION problem when calling glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S)?

The error analysis for glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S) sais that in the current state glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S) can not be executed. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a reminder: OpenGL accumulates errors, you must call glGetError in a loop until it returns GL_NO_ERROR to make sure you lifted the whole error stack.

Answer (score 2):

Please show us some code. My best guess is that you called *gl{Push,Pop}Matrix* and or *glEnable* within a *glBegin…glEnd* block, where those are not allowed.